# Javascript: sort() 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a two dimensional array where the first is the distance and second is the object:

```
[distance][object]
```

I need to order by distance - I'm trying something like this but it doesn`t work, someone could help me?

```
lista.sort((a, b) => {return a-b});
```

and

```
let t = lista.sort(sortFunction);

sortFunction(a, b) {
    if (a[0] === b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some real sample input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the the following should work for you - the idea here is to call `.sort()` on the "outer array" of your two-dimensional dataset, and pass a comparison function that tests the first element (ie the distance data) of each item being compared:

```js
var data = [
  [22, { object : 22 }],
  [10, { object : 10 }],
  [3, { object : 3 }],
  [50, { object : 50 }]
]

console.log('unsorted:', data)

data.sort((a, b) => {
  return a[0] - b[0]
})

console.log('sorted:', data)
```